# Как распарсить несколько строк в postgres?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

У меня есть поле с данными вида: `(a,b,c,d)`. Как мне получить эти данные в несколько колонок по нескольким строкам в `postgresql`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]?

То есть у меня есть поле `field`

```
select date, field
    from table

Outcome:
    date field
    01-01-2016    (a,b,c,d)
    02-01-2016    (e,f,g,h)

Desired Outcome:

    date          1  2  3  4
    01-01-2016    a  b  c  d
    02-01-2016    e  f  g  h
```

Comment: А поле у вас текстовое, вместе с круглыми скобками ? И надеюсь количество колонок фиксированное

Answer (score 1):

Преобразуем строку в массив и можем работать с отдельными элементами:

```
select date,arr[1] "1",arr[2] "2",arr[3] "3",arr[4] "4"
  from (
   select date,string_to_array(translate(field,'()',''),',') arr
     from tab
  ) X
```

Comment: Спасибо! сработало!

Comment: @user249955 Если ответ вас устроил, пожалуйста поставьте зеленую галочку под рейтингом ответа ;)

Answer (score 0):

Login: 06789-ivanov; IP 10.1.222.34; Time: 23.06.2015 19:43:35 это поле разбил на три части и сохранил в другую таблицу.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_data(
    s_input text
)
RETURNS void
AS $function$
DECLARE
    a_data text[];
BEGIN

    a_data := regexp_matches(s_input, '^Login: ([^;]+); IP ([\d\.]+); Time: ([\d\:\.\s]+)$');

    raise notice 'Login %', a_data[1];
    raise notice 'IP %', a_data[2];
    raise notice 'Time %', to_timestamp(a_data[3], 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS');

END;
$function$
LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE SECURITY DEFINER;
```

попробуйте в качестве примера сделать под себя

Comment: спасибо!:) хороший, но длинный подход